# How to pass more than one argument?

Tags: java, android, button

I am working on Android Studio 3.1.3.
My application consists of eight buttons. I am trying to pass more than one button as arguments from onClick method

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.button:
            pauseAudio(audioTwo, audioThree, audioFour, audioFive, audioSix, audioSeven, audioEight);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.birds);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            break;
```

to pauseAudio method,

```
public void pauseAudio(View view, Button audioOne, Button audioTwo, Button audioThree, Button audioFour, Button audioFive, Button audioSix, Button audioSeven, Button audioEight){

        if(audioOne.isEnabled()
                || audioTwo.isEnabled()
                || audioThree.isEnabled()
                || audioFour.isEnabled()
                || audioFive.isEnabled()
                || audioSix.isEnabled()
                || audioSeven.isEnabled()
                || audioEight.isEnabled()){
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer!=null){
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        }

    }
```

this is error it is showing when I hover over the underlined text
[image: this is error it is showing when I hover over the underlined text]
I am guessing the way I am passing argument is not the correct way, so please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would better to post app log cat here with a crash. In theory, you are doing everything right: you need to setup OnClickListener(this) for every button you have. And implement OnClickListener in your activity (Fragment) then as you did it you need a switch condition and check view.id

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the crash.

Comment: there's nothing in logs. It's blank.

Comment: @LoneWolf What device do you have? Sounds like you're using a Huawei

Comment: @LoneWolf Also, you're not even passing audioSeven and audioEight. First of all, remove the "this"-reference on fron of the view method calls.

Comment: @AntonioVlasic what sense does that make ? Though I am running it on Android's Emulator.

Comment: @AntonioVlasic when I am adding audioSeven and audioEight the program is not even compling.

Comment: @LoneWolf I thought you're using a Huawei as you don't see a crash log. Check my answer, it can help. Notice that I moved the "mediaPlayer != null" in front, maybe its not initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your code easier and hopefully work, try this:

```
public void pauseAudio(View... views) {
    for(View view : views) {
        if(view.isEnabled()) {
            if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
pauseAudio(audioOne, audioTwo, audioThree, ...);
```

**EDIT:**

Maybe also check if the view is not initialized:

```
if(view != null && view.isEnabled())
```

**EDIT 2:**

I'm glad to hear that it worked :) Here's a better explanation:

```
public void pauseAudio(View... views) { //Allow a dynamic initialization of an array of Views
    for(View view : views) { //Loop through the array
        if(view != null && view.isEnabled()) { //If the current view is not null and enabled
            if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){ //If the MediaPlayer is not null and playing
                mediaPlayer.stop(); //Stop the MediaPlayer
            }
            break; //Break the loop, as we have reached our usecase
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. Can you please explain what you did in there ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you publish the log after crash we could help you better. but I already see a control that can crash

```
  if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying () && mediaPlayer! = null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop ();
        }
```

. you could first check if mediaPlayer! = null before mediaPlayer.isPlaying () like this:

```
   if (mediaPlayer! = null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying ()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop ();
        }
```

Comment: No, it's working perfectly fine. The app started getting crashed after I passed more than one button as arguments. Also my logcat is blank, there is nothing in there. IDK how :/